# How to lock uninstalling an application with a password?

Tags: android

I'm developing an android app (let this app be X), and I want to force the user to use a password (he can change this password) when he trying to uninstall this program (X) **BUT** without using another lock application. I think I should use `service interface` that work in the background to check if the user want to uninstall this app (X).
**any help please and thanks in advance.**

Comment: I doubt Android will allow such a thing.

Comment: any explanation why?

Comment: IMHO and AFAIK the Android platform, it will not allow to restrict an un-installation unless it's a system app. Why? Because that is not a behavior ever wanted by Google AFAIK. The user should be able to remove any user application.

Comment: so why the lock apps(like AppLock and other lock-apps) can do such methods?

Comment: If the device is rooted then user also uninstall application by going in to save mode .

Comment: No. no the app (e.g. AppLock) doesn't take If the device is rooted in account. it works on the two device-modes (rooted & not-rooted).

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with "Drawing above other apps" `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`? But again, I'll doubt it will be possible to prompt with your app before an un-installation (because the un-installation process does not need to run the app).

Comment: yes, that's right, but this permission not enough, it must has a service (listener to check when the user is trying to uninstall an app). so how could this service be done if you know?